# Dockerfile exception module_not_found using node and express

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a simple node/express app that works correctly on its own, and for an exercise with docker-file I'm required to use docker to run it in a container.

I normally run my app with "**npm start**" and it works as expected, however while using Dockerfile to run it in docker I'm getting this exception:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 myuser/redbici

> redbicicletas@0.0.0 start /app
> node ./bin/www

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/bin/www'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! redbicicletas@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redbicicletas@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My Dockerfile file looks like this:

```
FROM node:12 

# Create app directory 
RUN mkdir /app 
WORKDIR /app 

  
# Install app dependencies 
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied 
# where available (npm@5+) 

COPY package*.json /app/ 
RUN npm install 

# If you are building your code for production 
# RUN npm ci --only=production 

# Bundle app source 

COPY . /app 

ENV NODE_ENV QA 
ENV PORT 3000 
EXPOSE 3000 

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and my package.json goes as follows:

```
{
  "name": "redbicicletas",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "startbootstrap-small-business": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

I don't get exactly why it isn't finding the folder if it is suppossed to copy all the original files to the new "app" folder, could someone help me understand? it better please?

thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Do you have - by any chance - a `.dockeringore`-file in the build context that exclude `/app/build` or `/app/build/www`?

Comment: I have a dockerignore but it sdoesnt include the build. it has:
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
README.md